# Vector Equation Question A-levels

Tags: vectors

With respect to an origin O, the points A and B have position vectors a and b respectively.
The point L lies on the line segment AB such that AL =
1/2 LB and the point M lies on OL produced such that OM = 6OL.

(i) Find the position vectors OL and OM, giving your answers in terms of a and b.

(ii) Show that the vector equation of the line BM can be written as r = 4Xa + (1 + X) b, where X is a parameter. Find in a similar form the vector equation of the line OA in terms of a parameter Y.

(iii) Find, in terms of a, the position vector of the point P where the lines BM and OA meet

(iv) it is given that a and b are unit vectors such that a and b are perpendicular. By using scalar product, find |PM|^2

I am unable to solve (iii) where the answer is OP = -4a. I am unsure of the steps to reach the answer.

Comment: What did you get for the line OA in (ii)?

Comment: The line is OA: r = Y * a

Comment: So put that equal to r in BM as the lines intersect. What must (1+X) be?

Comment: I can’t seem to understand how to find the position vector in terms of a after putting both equations equal to each other

Comment: $a$ and $b$ point in different directions so if a multiple of $a$ equals a multiple of $b$ what must that mean?

Comment: All points on the line $OA$ are multiples of the vector $a$. What value of $X$ results in $r = 4Xa + (1+X)b$ being a multiple of $a$?